# Order of loading of a .properties file in Java

Tags: class, loading

I am loading a .properties file from two different folders. The two properties file has same names but different contents .What will decide which properties file will get picked up.?

I have added the  paths of the two folders containing the properties file in a shared library in WebSphere . But the properties file which is getting picked up is the not the one I want ,whatever order I keep for the folder paths in the shared library.

Is there any definite order for picking up of properties files from folders.